# Authenticating a user who logged in in an external app within a web api

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, authorization

I am using Microsoft Authentication (Azure AD) to log in a user to an app.

I have a separate node.js API which I'd like an authenticated user to call but as it is an external API how do I check that the user who is requesting a resource is authenticated?

What is the flow, are there any good Node.js resources?

Comment: Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [protect the node js api with Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v1-nodejs-webapi). After that, you can implement a client(the app you used to login) that is able to pass authentication tokens to the API.

Here is an [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore) which contains a web API running on ASP.NET Core 2.0 protected by Azure AD. The web API is accessed by an ASP.NET Core 2.0 web application on behalf of the signed-in user.

The scenario is the same as yours, but I only find .net samples.